# static member is not being updated

Tags: c++, qt

I've come across very strange behavior. In my class I have QFileSystemModel declared as a static variable and this variable is getting initialized in the ctor, and it works, but as soon as I try to update its state (via some method from this class) this seems to not have any effect. But as soon as I change this variable to non-static everything works as it should. What is it about static variables that I'm missing?

```
class X:public QDialog
{
Q_OBJECT
static QFileSystemModel* model_;
public:
void update();
};

//cpp file
X::QFileSystemModel* model_  
X::X()
{
model_ = new QFileSystemModel(this);
}

void X::update()
{
model_->setNameFilters("*.h");//this will have absolutely no effect unless I make  
//model_ non static
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have more than one X being created and the new one overwrites the variable?

Comment: @RetiredNinja only one instance of this window is (AFAIC) created in my app. Even output to qDebug gives updated values, but display says something very different

Comment: As others have noticed:you need to make sure that only one instance of QFileSystemModel is created. It's wrong to place its creation in X c-tor as each time another X instance is created you need to execute `if(!model_)`. If QFileSystemModel is supposed to be shared among X instances, why is QFileSystemModel initialized with the address of the first instance of X? Who and when is gonna destroy QFileSystemModel instance? Change design: create QFileSystemModel on the stack (either as an independent object or static member of X) and move argument X* from its c-tor to its setNameFilters() method.

Comment: Why do you declare the model as static if you only create one instance of `X` ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it like this, to prevent multiple initialisations of `model_`:

```
//cpp file
X::QFileSystemModel* model_ = 0; // Not strictly necessary, but good for clarity
X::X()
{
if (model_ == 0) model_ = new QFileSystemModel(this);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why someone downvoted you. I see value in your answer, although it is not an answer to my question. +1

Comment: Although that solution can still have problems with race conditions if you have multiple threads.

Comment: @DouglasLeeder: As `X` is derived from `QDialog`, its constructor can only be called from the GUI thread, so no race condition can occur.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are creating a new `model_` for every new instance of your class `X` (each time the constructor is run) the problem you are describing seems to boil down to something a long the lines of; overwriting.

It's probably getting overwritten by another freshly created instance after you set some state in `X::update`.

That's the best answer I can give you without any more information regarding the matter.

#### Simple sample solution

```
struct Obj {
  Obj () {
    std::cerr << "model_: " << *model_ << std::endl;

    ++(*model_);
  }

  static int * model_;
};

int * Obj::model_ = new int (); // initialize the static member

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Obj a, b, c;
}
```

---

#### Typo?

I'm guessing this part of your snippet contains a typo, since a constructor cannot have a return type.

```
X::QFileSystemModel* model_  
X::X()
{
model_ = new QFileSystemModel(this);
}
```

Comment: there is typo indeed, semicolon should be after model_;

Comment: @user336635 debug your application and see how many times the object is created calling the specified constructor. A variable declared `static` doesn't differ in the states of what may be altered, and what not.